# Error while connecting ONVIF Device Manager to Geovision PTZ camera

Tags: onvif

Error is  : The content  type text/html of the response message does not match the content type of binding (application/soa+xml; charsset=utf-8), if using custom encoder ,be sure that the IsContentTypeSupported method is implemented properly. the first 1024 bytes of response were:' .... N So on ......

Comment: You are much more likely to get some assistance if you edit your question to include your failing code...

Comment: I don't think he has any code as he's using device manager.

Answer (score 1):

SOAP expects XML back and not HTML, therefore you get the error.

In my experience, you get HTML instead of XML when there's an error on the camera and it sends back some kind of description of the error.

To be able to understand what's going on, you should install wireshark, sniff the traffic and check what the camera sends back.